# Querying LeadStatus (including inactive)

Tags: soql, rest-api, metadata-api, tooling-api

It is trivial to retrieve all active `LeadStatus` values through the REST APIs, but I cannot see a way to pull in the inactive ones.

SOQL query to retrieve active lead statuses:

`SELECT Id, ApiName FROM LeadStatus`

Rather than "lazy create" these when encountered, is there a way of pulling the full picklist values in?

Comment: Could you please post the code you use to retrieve the active ones?

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to use the PicklistValueInfo. E.g.

```
SELECT Id, DurableId, Value, Label, IsDefaultValue, IsActive, ValidFor FROM PicklistValueInfo Where entityParticleId = 'Lead.Status'
```

However, dispite having an `IsActive` column that only returns the currently active picklist values.

Instead you could try the Tooling API FieldDefinition.Metadata. E.g.

```
SELECT Id,DurableId,QualifiedApiName,EntityDefinitionId,NamespacePrefix,DeveloperName,
    DataType,Metadata,FullName 
FROM FieldDefinition 
WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Lead' AND QualifiedApiName = 'Status'
```

The Metadata should contain the picklist values applicable to that field.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I am not seeing the actual picklist values in the Metadata array. Instead it is an array of null values.

`"Metadata" => array:52 [
    "caseSensitive" => null
    "customDataType" => null
    "defaultValue" => null
    "deleteConstraint" => null
    "deprecated" => null
    "description" => null
    "displayFormat" => null
    "displayLocationInDecimal" => null
    "encrypted" => null
    "escapeMarkup" => null
    "externalDeveloperName" => null
    "externalId" => null
    "formula" => null
    "formulaTreatBlanksAs" => null`

Comment: HI Daniel. The Tooling API FieldDefinition.Metadata does not return any values and just shows as [object Object]. Do you have any other suggestions here?

Comment: @Swetha How are you querying the tooling API? I'm guessing you are using the developer console if you are seeing [object Object]. Try something like workbench that will show you the complete response.

Comment: I now tried with workbench GET request as 
/services/data/v46.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Id,Label,DurableId,EntityDefinitionId,Metadata+FROM+FieldDefinition+WHERE+EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName+='Lead'+AND+QualifiedApiName='Status' .Though the metadata is displayed, it does not have the inactive picklist values and shows null value labels. Am I missing something?